# MsBuild: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: angularjs, node.js, msbuild, npm-install, ng-build

I am trying to build my angular solution using MsBuilds.

Following is my code snippet

```
>     <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)\Dev\AngularUI" />
>     <Exec Command="npm install -g @angular/cli"  WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)\Dev\AngularUI" />
>     <Exec Command="ng build --prod" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)\Dev\AngularUI" />
```

While the `npm i` command works fine , i get the error `'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command` on the `ng build --prod` command.

I try to run the same commands from cmd and it works fine from the same build account as well.

Comment: Hi. Have you fond the answer?

Comment: yes, I had to re install node.js on the server from the Build agent account.

Comment: did you deploy this app on Linux server or Windows? I had similar problem and I had to replace ng build with script which invoked ng build indirectly

Comment: Deployed it on Windows. Reinstalling Node.js from the build account fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm run ng build`. The only issue with this is it omits any other parameter like `--prod` or `--test` after build.

Following are the commands what i am using to run my angular build successfully from Jenkins.Doing it the dirty way by setting up the path variables. Don't know if there is a cleaner way to do this. This does execute the commands properly without omitting anything.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;

@echo on
cmd /c npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

echo yarn Install
cmd /c yarn

echo Build    
ng build --prod --aot=true
```

Probably you can remove `cmd /c` as well, will still work. Using it just in case of errors to handle stuff properly.